# Proper use of DrawRect override - can I prevent view stretching?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

**Edit: Simplified version of the verbose question below: Can you update the bounds of a UIView via a subclassed drawRect without causing the contents of the view to stretch?**

---

I am building a news reader application and have been looking at how I can split my UIView into columns and still page the content. I believe I have the basic coding of the columns down (splitting an XML nodes contents into an array by paragraph, and then parsing through detecting the total area required as to not cut off the paragraph.)

The problem I am having is I cannot update the ContentBounds without the text stretching, even though the content inside is large enough to support an un stretched view.

Basically this:

```
contentBounds = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height+COLUMN_YPOS);

[renderer updateContentBounds:contentBounds];
```

is causing this: (full code below image)
[image: Stretched Image]

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

NSString *string = contentString;
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>" withString:@"\n\n"];

// column width
int COLUMN_WIDTH = self.bounds.size.width/2-40;
int COLUMN_HEIGHT = self.bounds.size.height-100;

int COLUMN_XPOS = 20;
int COLUMN_YPOS = 0;

int PAGE_HEIGHT = COLUMN_HEIGHT + 40;

CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(COLUMN_WIDTH, COLUMN_HEIGHT-20);

NSArray *paragraphs = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

NSString *textBuffer = @"";
NSString *preBuffer = @"";
NSString *currentStringSegment;

for (int i=0; i<[paragraphs count]; i++) {

    currentStringSegment = [paragraphs objectAtIndex:i];

    preBuffer = textBuffer;
    textBuffer = [textBuffer stringByAppendingString:@"\n\n"];
    textBuffer = [textBuffer stringByAppendingString:currentStringSegment];

    CGSize expectedSize = [textBuffer sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(COLUMN_WIDTH, COLUMN_HEIGHT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    if(expectedSize.height > maximumSize.height){

        [preBuffer drawInRect:CGRectMake(COLUMN_XPOS, COLUMN_YPOS, COLUMN_WIDTH, COLUMN_HEIGHT) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:16] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        i--;
        textBuffer = @"";
        preBuffer = @"";

        if(COLUMN_XPOS > 20) {

            COLUMN_XPOS = 20;
            COLUMN_YPOS += PAGE_HEIGHT;

        } else {

            COLUMN_XPOS = COLUMN_WIDTH + 60;

        }

    }

}

if(![preBuffer isEqualToString:@""] && preBuffer != nil){

    [preBuffer drawInRect:CGRectMake(COLUMN_XPOS, COLUMN_YPOS, COLUMN_WIDTH, COLUMN_HEIGHT) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:16] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

}

contentBounds = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);

[renderer updateContentBounds:contentBounds];

}
```

Comment: Have you set the content mode of the UIView to something other than UIViewContentModeScaleToFill? Are you sure you don't want to use a label or text view or even a web view? Handling it in drawRect means you are creating a bitmap, so, you have to do all the work yourself such as placement and scale before rendering it.

Comment: I have debated using a web view, but I want to be able to dynamically render pages with columns split by page. Can I adjust the scale of the view from within the drawRect? Or do I need to pass the new dimensions out to another function to handle?

Comment: I've got to ask: Why not just use UILabels as subviews of your paging view to serve as the columns? Or a UITextView if you want scrolling? It just seems like a lot of unneeded effort.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of a `UIView` when the bounds change is determined by the `contentMode` property.

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html) you will read:

> the value in the `contentMode` property determines whether the bitmap should be scaled to fit the new bounds or simply pinned to one corner or edge of the view.

By default `contentMode` is set to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` which, as you can read in the same doc page,

> causes the view’s contents to be scaled to fit the new frame size.

You may want to change the `contentMode` of your view to a non-distorting behavior, such as `UIViewContentModeTop`, which will center the content aligned at the top in the view’s bounds.

You can find all the possible values for `contentMode` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIViewContentModeScaleToFill).

Comment: Specifically, if you want the system to send `drawRect:` when you change the view's bounds, set `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIScrollView in paging mode.

[Scrolling Using Paging Mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html)

You can put a UIWebView inside the UIScrollView and use HTML/CSS to create your columns, turn off the user interaction on the web view, and use the UIScrollView to scroll through the columns horizontally.